# encryption without predefined libraries

Tags: java, c#, encryption

I have tried to find tutorials about encryption based purely on own developed code.

For example in Java you have the javax.crypto package, in C# you have the Windows.Security.Cryptography dll. However I am trying to find a tutorial how to encrypt data with bits/bytes without using predefined classes/dll.

Does anyone know where and if there are such tutorials?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is very unwise to develop your own encryption algorithms. It might be useful only as a school exercise. Otherwise it could be dangerous!

However, if you really have to do it on your own, have a look at some existing source code as inspiration:

https://www.bouncycastle.org/

or read the technical specification of the cipher you want to implement, AES for example:

http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/fips/fips197/fips-197.pdf

Comment: I understand the risks that come with it, however I am just very curious how it works and how the algorithms are made up!
Thanx for the help.